# Using ajax, how to get notify only if there is any update in the received data

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function refreshText(){
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "user.php",
        data: "data1=1",
        success: function(result){
         $(".msg").html(result);
         setTimeout(refreshText, 5000);
         }});
    });
```

Initially when it loads it should not notify or alert, but after every timeout it should alert me if there is any update in the data..Exactly how it works in chat. Could any one please help me on this, I am bit new to programming....

Comment: What do you mean by "update in the received data"?

Comment: I mean, It should notify or popup something, if there is any update in database..... Like chat

Answer (score 2):

Just store the last result into a cookie and check it on ajax success:

```
$(function(){
    refreshText();
});

var last_response; // define this variable to save the result
function refreshText(){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "user.php",
        data: "data1=1",
        success: function(result){
            if( result === last_response ) return;
            last_response = result;
            $(".msg").html(result);
            setTimeout(refreshText, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var Results = "";
 $(document).ready(function refreshText() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "user.php",
         data: "data1=1",
         success: function(result) {
             if (result != Results) {
                 result = Results;
                 alert("Change...");
             }
             $(".msg").html(result);
             setTimeout(refreshText, 5000);
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: This code alerts me every time without any update in my data received..??

Comment: this will alert only on result change

Comment: Initially the "Results" is 0 and it enters into the condition and alerts me at every timeout....

Answer (score 0):

Save your result value and compare it each time. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(

    var last_result;

    function refreshText(){
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "user.php",
            data: "data1=1",
            success: function(result){

                 if(result == last_result){
                     // result is different
                     $(".msg").html(result);
                 }

                 last_result = result; // save the result

                 setTimeout(refreshText, 5000);
         }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result returned by the ajax like :

```js
    success : function(result){ 
      if(result is changed){ 
      //do some operation
      }
      else
        // do somthing else
    }
```

or you can also check the same on the server side for any change